# How to append user_id to Rails file upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an app where users can upload csv files to load data onto our platform. I have a form that lets a user upload a file and a method that saves the file in a specified folder. I want to append the user_id to the filename. How would I do that?

my form:

```
<%= form_tag import_listings_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :my_file %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
<% end %>
```

my controller method:

```
def import
    tmp = params[:my_file].tempfile
    file = File.join("public", params[:my_file].original_filename)
    FileUtils.cp tmp.path, file
end
```

For example, if a user uploads test.csv and their user_id is 20. I want the new filename to be test20.csv

Comment: Well, all the code is right there. What changes have you tried to make? Note the generation of the local file path (`file = ..`) which is promptly used. (However, wishing to save the user_id appended sounds like larger design issue that should be addressed; users should probably not be able to write into the same directory.)

Comment: I tried `params[:my_file].original_filename + params[:user_id]` but this gives me test.csv20 - I want the file name to be test20.csv. I tried putting the user param after the file param but it gives me an error.

Comment: You can use the [File module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html) combined with concatenation. See File#extname and File#basename. Start on IRB/REPL, given `id = 20; s = "foo.csv"`, how would generate the string `"foo_20.csv"` given the above methods?

Answer (score -1):

A bit ugly but this should do the job... basically extracting the file extension (obtaining the last string after the '.'), appending the user id and adding the extension back:

```
x = params[:my_file].original_filename.split('.')
x[x.length - 2] += params[:user_id] 
file = File.join("public", x.join('.'))
```

Comment: very close. I get test.20csv - How do I move the 20 before the .? Should be a simple fix but I don't understand parts of your code.

Comment: This is not at all a good solution. There are built in methods in Ruby std lib as mentioned by @user2864740 in a comment to the question. Use those methods to get the desired result. Additionally this solution breaks if the filename contains a dot. Down-voting this for these reasons.

Comment: It does not break if the filename contains dots, the join('.') with dots adds them back again! (it was however - before the edit - modifying the extension name instead of the filename as Moosa pointed out). I didn't say it was the perfect solution but it works.